# R Studio: How to perform separate data wrangling procedures for different values of a variable into a list of individual dataframes?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| Geography | Dates      | Sales  | Avg_Volume |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| A         | 2020-01-01 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| A         | 2020-01-02 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| A         | 2020-01-03 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| A         | 2020-01-04 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| A         | 2020-01-05 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| B         | 2020-01-01 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| B         | 2020-01-02 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| B         | 2020-01-03 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| B         | 2020-01-04 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| B         | 2020-01-05 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| C         | 2020-01-01 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| C         | 2020-01-02 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| C         | 2020-01-03 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| C         | 2020-01-04 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| C         | 2020-01-05 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| D         | 2020-01-01 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| D         | 2020-01-02 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| D         | 2020-01-03 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| D         | 2020-01-04 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| D         | 2020-01-05 |        |            |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
```

I would like to have 3 dataframes dedicated to City B,C,D that looks like this (I need A_Sales to be always present:

```
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| Dates      | A_Sales  | B_Sales | B_Avg_Volume |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-01 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-02 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-03 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-04 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-05 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
```

```
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| Dates      | A_Sales  | C_Sales | C_Avg_Volume |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-01 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-02 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-03 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-04 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-05 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
```

```
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| Dates      | A_Sales  | D_Sales | D_Avg_Volume |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-01 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-02 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-03 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-04 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-01-05 |          |         |              |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+
```

Currently this is what I have:

```
data_A <- data %>% 
  filter(Geography == "A") %>% 
  rename("A_Sales" = Sales) %>% 
  select(Dates, A_Sales)


data_B <- data %>% 
  filter(Geography == 'B') %>% 
  rename("B_Sales" = Sales)%>%
  rename("B_Avg_Volume" = Avg_Volume)%>%
  select(Dates, B_Sales, B_Avg_Volume)

data_a_n_b <- data_A %>% 
  left_join(data_B, by = 'Dates')
```

This is very redundant and inefficient, because I would have to change `Geography == '...')` to `"B,C,D..."` everytime and re-run.  My real data has ~ 50 cities so it is unrealistic for me to do this process for each city individually.

**What is a elegant way to **batch processing this process**?**

I am imagining the end result be **a list of dataframes** for city B,C,D ... and so on,  with the name of each individual dataframe be the city name. This way I can easily access each individual dataframe. For example, calling `data_result$C` (or sth like that) will give me the dataframe for City C. Any other output format is also welcomed, as long as accessing individual dataframe is easy.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `purrr` this could be achieved like so:

1. Split your df by Geography
2. Loop over the list (except for region "A") and join the dfs to the one for region A
3. Do some renaming

```r
set.seed(42)

dat <- data.frame(
  Geography = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 4),
  Dates = rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-04"), by = "1 day"), 4),
  Sales = runif(4 * 4),
  Avg_Volume = runif(4 * 4)
)

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat_list <- dat %>% 
  split(.$Geography) %>% 
  map(select, -Geography)

imap(dat_list[setdiff(names(dat_list), "A")], function(x, y) {
  left_join(dat_list[["A"]], x, by = "Dates", suffix = c(paste0("_", y), "_A")) %>% 
    rename_with(~ str_replace(.x, "(Sales|Avg_Volume)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1"), -Dates) %>% 
    select(-A_Avg_Volume)
})
#> $B
#>        Dates   B_Sales B_Avg_Volume   A_Sales
#> 1 2020-01-01 0.9148060    0.9782264 0.6417455
#> 2 2020-01-02 0.9370754    0.1174874 0.5190959
#> 3 2020-01-03 0.2861395    0.4749971 0.7365883
#> 4 2020-01-04 0.8304476    0.5603327 0.1346666
#> 
#> $C
#>        Dates   C_Sales C_Avg_Volume   A_Sales
#> 1 2020-01-01 0.9148060    0.9782264 0.6569923
#> 2 2020-01-02 0.9370754    0.1174874 0.7050648
#> 3 2020-01-03 0.2861395    0.4749971 0.4577418
#> 4 2020-01-04 0.8304476    0.5603327 0.7191123
#> 
#> $D
#>        Dates   D_Sales D_Avg_Volume   A_Sales
#> 1 2020-01-01 0.9148060    0.9782264 0.9346722
#> 2 2020-01-02 0.9370754    0.1174874 0.2554288
#> 3 2020-01-03 0.2861395    0.4749971 0.4622928
#> 4 2020-01-04 0.8304476    0.5603327 0.9400145
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I encountered this error: "Error in map(., select, -Geography) : object 'Geography' not found"

Comment: When you run the code on my example data or when you test it on your data?

Comment: I figured it out. My dplyr library has been malfunctioning since this morning. I had to forcefully call dplyr:: for simple functions like select, filter etc.

Comment: Hm. Weird. Maybe some name clashing with another package or ...

Answer (score 0):

I took Stefan's setup dataframe and added another way to do it. The steps are:

1. Get a list of the list of city names (excluding A). The way I wrote it assumes A is first, but you could also use discard() to remove "A" from the city list.
2. Use map with filter to get a list of data frames that have A and each city in cities. set_names to make sure each list element is accessible by its city name
3. Take each data frame in the list and pivot_wider, then select everything by Avg_Volume for A.

```
#Set up a sample data frame
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

dat <- tibble(
  Geography = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 4),
  Dates = rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-04"), by = "1 day"), 4),
  Sales = runif(4 * 4),
  Avg_Volume = runif(4 * 4)
)

#Code to wrangle into list of filtered, wide format data frames
library(dpylyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

cities <- unique(dat$Geography)[-1]
dat_list <- map(cities, ~ filter(dat, Geography == "A" | Geography == .x)) %>% set_names(cities)
dat_list_wider <- map(dat_list, 
                      ~pivot_wider(.x, id_cols = "Dates", 
                                   names_from = "Geography", 
                                   values_from = c("Sales","Avg_Volume")) %>% 
                      select(-Avg_Volume_A))
```